# Quicksort in Θ(n lg n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, code-analysis, quicksort

This is a question to people who are programmers for a living - 
I just proved (using the Master theorem) that if we use quicksort and we pick the pivot to be the median of the the subarray we are partitioning (using the median of medians algorithm with Θ(n) worst case run time) then the worst case run time of quicksort is Θ(n lg n) - so basically this means that this version of quicksort is as good as it can get.

My question now is - does anyone implement quicksort like this in practice? Or is it just one of those nice theoretical things that are actually not good in real life?

PS - I don't need proofs of what I'm stating, I just want to know if this is being widely known/useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known (see the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Selection-based_pivoting) entry), but since in practice the worst case is relatively rare, the added overhead of an O(N) selection algorithm on the average case is generally considered unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on where you're working. 
So far, personally, I never actually implemented it - But I really think it varies, depending on the requirements of your workplace.

Answer (score 1):

When you made partition around some pivot, you already have "quality" of the pivot (how evenly it divides array). If it's lower than some threshold, you can try some smarter ways to select pivot. This keeps time complexity O(n*log n) and keeps constants low, because complex selection is done rarely.

If I don't mistake C++ STL uses something like this, but I haven't any links - that's from a conversation on work.

**update**

C++ STL (at least the one in Visual Studio) seems to do a different thing:

1. Perform partition
2. Unconditionally sort the smaller part by recursion (since it cannot be bigger than half that's safe for O(n*log n))
3. Handle the larger part in the same loop (without recursive call)

If number of iterations exceeds approx. `1.5 log2(N)`, it switches to heap sort which is O(n*log n).

Comment: The idea with the threshold seems the neatest to me tbh. What do you mean by 'limits the number of divisions'? Is that the number of partitions or sth else ?

Comment: @kaval: I've expanded that part a bit.